# Can Strapi be deployed through Amazon Lightsail?

Tags: strapi, amazon-lightsail

So far I have set up a mySQL server on Amazon lightsail and have succesfully used it while running strapi locally. How do I deploy Strapi itself on lightsail and get a link to access it through a browser?

I have read through https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/deployment/amazon-aws.html, but the guide is for AWS EC2. Do the same steps apply to lightsail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out. Please let me know if something is wrong or can be done better:

1. Start an Ubuntu instance in lightsail, I picked the 2GB RAM tier because that's the min requirements for Strapi to run (they have them listed in their documents) and give it a static IP address.
2. Install node onto your server:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | sudo -E bash -
...
sudo apt-get install nodejs
...
node -v && npm -v
```

3. I cloned my project from github, so a lot of node modules weren't imported due to .gitignore. Simply cd into the project direcotry and run node install to install all the missing dependencies.
4. run npm build to build the panel, then npm start
5. it should tell you to go to localhost:1337, instead go to [your server's IP address]:1337
6. your Strapi app should be on the screen

Comment: out question scope, but did you host on the same lightsail instance your frontend app?

Comment: Yes, then I used [PM2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) to run them. My frontend used port 3000

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, The **strapi** can be deployed to Lightsail. But there will be no advantages.

Lightsail must be configured as a Node.js server.

1. Deploy from github
2. Install PM2 Runtime

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to allow all access in the networking tab and it only worked after that